# A function to delete backspace for a pointer to string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I need to write a function to delete the backspace and shift all all subsequent characters. This is what I have so far.

```
int ProcessBackspaces(char *rpn_sentence)
{
        int i=0;
        char *array [MAX];
        char *b_token;
        b_token = strtok(rpn_sentence, "\b");
        while (b_token!=NULL){
            array[i]=b_token;
            i++;
        }    
}
```

I am stuck at how to make the pass in pointer(char *rpn_sentence) point to every single elements of the array of pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to make the pass in pointer(char *rpn_sentence) point to every single elements of the array of pointer.

Simply  increment the pointer (or a copy of it);

Consider also that the string may have 0 (be quick then) or more than 1 backspace (only copy characters once).

```
char *ProcessBackspaces(char *rpn_sentence) {
  char *src = strchr(rpn, '\b'); // Find first quickly
  if (src) {
    char *dest = src;
    src++;
    while (*src) {
      if (*src != '\b') {
        *dest++ = *src;  // Save non-backspaces, increment destination
      }
      src++;             // Increment source
    }
    *dest = '\0';      
  }
  return rpn;  // Perhaps return start of string
}
```